# How to subset from a long list?

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list `x` with millions of entries in it. And I want to put all the entries with a length larger than one into a new list `z`. How can I do this efficiently in R?

I tried this code, and R just keeps running for a long time.

```
z=NULL
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  if(length(x[[i]])!=1) z=list(z,x[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, that code won't work (along with being slow): you might have meant `z=list()`, then `z=c(z, list(x[[i]]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
z = x[sapply(x, length) > 1]
```

Comment: Thanks David! It really saves me a lot of time!

Answer (score 6):

This is one case where you want to use `vapply`:

```
z <- x[vapply(x, length, integer(1)) > 1L]
```

Here are benchmarks comparing `sapply` and `vapply`:

```
A <- list( x = c(), y = c(1), z = c(1, 2))
B <- A[sample(1:3, 1e7, replace = TRUE)]
system.time(sapply(B, length))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   55.95    0.54   56.50 
system.time(vapply(B, length, integer(1)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.78    0.00    6.78
```

Comment: Thanks flodel！I have an extra question. Which time should I refer to when comparing the efficiency of different functions?